# python3 dbf module. trounle with appen cyrillic latters

Tags: python, dbf

trying to make dbf, all goes as normal but if im try to append cyrillic latters:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

im know that python have probles with unicode but may be somehow im cant put cyrillic latters in dbf?

code:

```
table = dbf.Table(ex_file_name)
table.open(mode=dbf.READ_WRITE)
for r in rows_massive:
    table.append(
        (datetime.strptime(r[0], '%d.%m.%Y'), r[1], r[2], PLACEPAY, prefix_name))
```

PLACEPAY pay have cyrillic latters in position 0-6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the dbf was not created with a code-page, so it defaulted to ASCII.  You can try creating the table with code page 866 (Russian).  If creating with the `dbf`<sup>1</sup> module, it looks like this:

```
table = dbf.Table('filename.dbf', 'field1 D, field2 C(10), ...,'  codepage='cp866')
```

If you cannot create the dbf yourself, but whatever other software you are using is broken enough to read non-ASCII data in an ASCII-specified dbf file, then you can simply override the code page whenever you open the table in Python (it's the same as above, but without the field specifications):

```
table = dbf.Table('filename.dbf', codepage='cp866')
```

Alternatively, if you are only using Python, and are only using the `dbf` module, you can try the undocumented and incompatible-with-other-dbf-libraries code page of `'utf8'` -- if you do you will want to make your character fields bigger, since the number of bytes needed to represent certain Unicode code-points is greater than one (worst case scenario is four bytes per code-point, so the safe route would be to increase the size of your character fields four times; i.e. a `C(6)` field would be `C(24)`).

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the `dbf` module.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpfull. And thatnk you for this module, it save aroud a 3 days of my life in a month)